# Load angular tree repeat plugin in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to run the following example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kbt85s6q/4/). Perhaps I did something wrong by loading the plugin and libraries. Could some one please examine the issue?

```
<ul>
<li sf-treepeat="node in children of treeData">
  {{node.name}}
  <ul>
    <li sf-treecurse>This should be removed</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why the node name didn't show, at least it solved all of the console errors.

Please refer to the updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/kbt85s6q/5/

```
var app = angular.module("treeRepeatApp", []);
```

Comment: I updated your jsfiddle to 'var app = angular.module("treeRepeatApp", ['sf.treeRepeat']);' now its working. It seems it wont work properly because I add jquery and angular before.